# 0 device supported in play store supported list

Tags: android, google-play, android-manifest

I have problem with the upload my apk to Play store.i uploaded my apk to play store.but i faces some problem.play store shows there are **0 supported device**.

1.What is the reason behind this?

Androidmanifast.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="your_package" >

    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.camera"
        android:required="true" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_SIP" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.android.launcher.permission.INSTALL_SHORTCUT"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.KILL_BACKGROUND_PROCESSES" />

    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.sip.voip"
        android:required="true" />
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.wifi"
        android:required="true" />
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.microphone"
        android:required="true" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="Concall"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="ConCall"
            android:noHistory="true" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".Register"
            android:label="Create Account"
            android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity2"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".Forgotpassword"
            android:label="Forgot Password"
            android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity2"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".JoinConfWithoutLogin"
            android:label="Join Without Sign-in"
            android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity2"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >

            <!-- The meta-data element is needed for versions lower than 4.1 -->
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="com.onepgr.samcom.apicalldemo2.MainActivity" />
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".TabBarControll"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_tab_bar_controll"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
            <intent-filter>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".Tab1"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_tab1"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".Tab2"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_tab2"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".Tab3"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_tab3"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".Tab4"
            android:label="Tab4"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".InviteUserUdated"
            android:isScrollContainer="false"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_invite_user_udated"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustPan" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".StartCallActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_start_call"
            android:parentActivityName=".InviteUserUdated"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity2"
            android:label="Concall"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
            <intent-filter>
                <data
                    android:host="onepgr.com"
                    android:scheme="http" />

                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".TabHostActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_tab_host" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".HomeTab"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_home_tab" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".NewCallControll"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_new_call_controll" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".NewCallControll2"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_new_call_controll2"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".WebViewTest"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_web_view_test" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".UploadAvtivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_upload_avtivity" >
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Build.gradle(module)

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    dependencies {
        compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
        compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.0.0'
    }
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "app_id"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    packagingOptions{
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
    compile files('libs/httpcore-4.3.3.jar')
    compile files('libs/httpmime-4.3.6.jar')
}
```

Help me solve this issue.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please post your gradle config as well. I suspect your min-sdk level is 23.

Comment: I would suggest bringing down your target and compile sdk versions and trying again. See if that works.

Comment: in the AndroidManifest.xml the why haven't you put the value for package name tag?

Comment: My target sdk and compile sdk level 22 is the reason behind 0 supported device in play store?@SaketJain

Comment: its my package name @rj

Comment: Did you try my answer?

Comment: yes wait.if its work than i will give you upword and right mark@rj

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using android.software.sip.voip, not android.hardware.sip.voip. I think your app is showing up with 0 supported devices because Google Play does not know about android.hardware.sip.voip. Also, you should set android:required="false" unless your app cannot function at all without SIP/VOIP support.

Comment: why i need to set require="false" ?@rj

Comment: Okay, you can set it as true if it is really necessary and if the app doesn't work without it. The issue is with "android.hardware.sip.voip" only

Comment: our app is using voip functinality so it it require for this app.What can i set it "false" or "true"?@rj

Comment: Okay then set it as true, upload and let me know if it shows the supported devices